# "Ihren Namen". Is there a grammar problem here?

Tags: possessive

Warum sagt man z.B. "Schreiben Sie Ihren Namen?" Soll das nicht "Ihre Namen" oder "Ihren Name" sein?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The noun **Name** belongs to the so called **Weak declination**, requiring an additional **-n** even in singular.

There is a bunch of other nouns, which behave like this:

> Die Mähne eines Löwe**n**
>
> Mein Freund Karl wurde von einem Bär**en** angegriffen.
>
> Frag diesen Junge**n** nach seiner Mutter.
>
> Hast du schon meinen Nachbar**n** gesehen?
>
> Joseph hat den Polizist**en** aufs Übelste beschimpft.

There are even rules which nouns belong to this group. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Schwache_und_gemischte_Deklination or http://www.google.com

Answer (score 6):

In der Formulierung „***Schreiben Sie Ihren Namen***“ steht das Nomen „*Name*“ im Akkusativ Singular; die Flexionsform ist in diesem Fall „*[Namen](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/name:N:M)*“.

Die Formulierung „***Ihre Namen***“ wäre dann korrekt, wenn der **Plural** verwendet werden soll. Das ist m.E. aber ungebräuchlich, da mit „Name“ regelmäßig der komplette Name, also Vor- und Familienname gemeint ist. Der Plural würde m.E. nur dann verwendet werden, wenn gerade mehrere Namen geschrieben werden sollen, etwa alle Vornamen (nicht nur den „Rufnamen“), evtl. vielleicht bei Doppelnamen oder Geburts- und Ehenamen. Das hängt aber stark von der Situation ab.

Also: „***Ihre Namen***“ ist grammatikalisch möglich, wäre aber m.E. fehl am Platz; „***Ihren Name***“ ist grammatikalisch falsch, da statt des Akkusativ der Nominativ verwendet (bzw. der Akkusativ falsch gebildet) wird.

Grammatikalisch korrekt wäre es auch, die Aufforderung „***Schreiben Sie Ihre Namen***“ an mehrere Personen zu richten. Die Bedeutung der Aufforderung hängt auch hier also vom Kontext, von der jeweiligen Situation ab.

Comment: Ihre Namen als Plural wäre gängig, wenn man eine Gruppe von Personen anspricht, z.B. beim wenn sich Leute in eine Besucherliste eintragen: "Schreiben Sie bitte ihre Namen und ihre Telefonnummer auf diese Liste."

Answer (score -2):

That's correct. It has to be Ihre**n** Name**n**, not either/or.

Comment: Could you elaborate? If it is singular, then it is "Ihren Name" because it is akkusative? And in plural, the possessive is "Ihre".

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, really. It's an accusative object and _ihr_ needs to match that. Yes, this is singular. If it's meant to be plural, it would indeed be _Ihre Namen_ (your names). ETA: There are much more elaborate answers in the meantime. So, what they say.